# Trying to create a Django model instance via a form, but I only want to extract some fields from the form and set others manually

Tags: python, django, forms

I'm trying to create a gallery app in Django. I have two models: Pic and Profile, which represent an individual picture and a user profile respectively. Each user has a profile instance created when they sign up for the website. Here are the models:

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, related_name="profile")

class Pic(models.Model):
    profile = models.ForeignKey(Profile, blank=True, null=True)
    photo = models.ImageField(upload_to = "photos/%Y/%m/%d/")
```

I want users to be able to upload an image through an HTML form. When they upload the image I want to create a Pic whose ImageField corresponds to the upload. I've created a ModelForm for the Pic model to accomplish this. Here's the form as of now:

```
class PicForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Pic
        fields = ('photo',)
```

And the upload_image view:

```
def upload_image(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = PicForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('home')
        else:
            return redirect('upload_image')
    else: 
        form = PicForm()
        return render(request, 'pics/upload_image.html', {
            'form': form
        })
```

So the problem is, I want the user to be able to set the photo field of the new Pic via the form, but not the profile field. I want that to be set to the user's profile. How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try it:

```
if form.is_valid():
    pic = form.save(commit=False)
    pic.profile = request.user.profile
    pic.save()
    return redirect('home')
```

more details for [form save method](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/forms/modelforms/#the-save-method)

Answer (score 2):

[Bear Brown's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46550965/3202958) is a simple way that should do the trick. However, it will be less [`dry`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) if you will be using the same form on multiple locations. (Even though it is not much profit you will have in your current situation, but it might give you more profit in the future) Since this is a question that is asked quite often, i'll try to explain it a little more detailed to make it `dry`, and who knows it might benefit you or anyone else having the same question. Besides, keeping the form logic in your `form` is often a good thing to do.

So, getting the `user.profile` in the `PicForm` can be achieved by passing the `request.user` in your `view` method or function to the class as an `keyword argument` (`kwarg`), and `pop` it in the `__init__`. The popped `user` can then be used in the override of the `save` method in your `PicForm`

The first two parameters of the [`BaseModelForm`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/forms/models.py#L278) take the `data` and `files` that you have passed as `request.POST` and `request.FILES`. To add the parameter that accepts the `kwargs`, you'll have to add the `__init__` method in your `PicForm` that accepts `*args, **kwargs`.

Eventually you will have to apply the near same logic as mentioned by Bear Brown. You will have to get the data from the form by saving it without committing. At that point you have to add the user's profile to the `Pic` instance and finally actually save it while committing.

Since you have the `related_name` set, you can get the profile from the user that submits the form by `self.user.profile`, since we defined `self.user` in the `__init__` by popping the `user` from the `kwargs`.

```
class PicForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Pic
        fields = ('photo',)

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.user = kwargs.pop('user')
        super(PicForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

   def save(self, commit=True):
       pic = super(PicForm, self).save(commit=False)
       pic.profile = self.user.profile
       if commit:
           pic.save()
       return pic
```

When you have the situation above, you can now build your form by passing `request.POST`, `request.FILES` and `request.user`:

```
form = PicForm(request.POST, request.FILES, user=request.user)
if form.is_valid():
    form.save()
```

Why is this more future-proof and `dry` you might ask? Imagine yourself having the `PicForm` used in 15 different locations, which I can imagine with a form like this. If you want to change the logic while saving, for example based on the `user`, you'd have to change it on 15 different locations. While using the override, you might only need to change it in one location (which is not *always true* of course)

Anyway, chose the right fit for you.

Comment: In both cases the form will not validate the field 'user' and als not field that are related with user. I'd like to see a solution for that other then setting the field this and including it via a HiddenField.